# Deleting records from table

Tags: asp.net

[image]

In the above photo I have a table containing a list of users that are add dynamically in the table.
I want when I click on the red-cross image button the corresponding user to be deleted from the database.

Here is the code that fills the table:

```
/****** Filling the originators table ********/
          string[] oa1 = originator;
            for (int i = 0; i < oa1.Length; i++)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                users_table.Rows.Add(row);
                for (int colCount = 0; colCount < 4; colCount++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    if (colCount == 0)
                    {
                        cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(oa1[i]));
                    }
                    else if (colCount == 1)
                    {
                        cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("|"));
                    }
                    else if (colCount == 2)
                    {
                        LLKB userInfo = new LLKB();
                        cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(userInfo.InfoGetter(oa1[i].Trim(), "name")));
                    }
                    else if (colCount == 3)
                    {
                        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton();
                        btn.ImageUrl = "img/DeleteRed.png";
                        btn.ID = oa1[i] + "_" + i;
                        btn.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(delete_originator);
                        cell.Controls.Add(btn);
                    }
                }
            }
```

and here is the method that show do the deletion:

```
public void delete_originator(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code here
    }
```

So, what do you suggest I write in the deletion method??

or if you have another idea...

Comment: Can you use listview for this.http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Asp.net+listview+delete&oq=Asp.net+listview+delete&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3...2408.2408.2.2636.2.2.0.0.0.0.250.250.2-1.1.0.cqn%2Crate_low%3D0-025%2Crate_high%3D0-025%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Ccconf%3D1-0%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D1.1.0.0.5TkzTAkUJv4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=aa2b9cfcf135efc9&biw=1024&bih=677

Comment: well, the thing is that the users are added on demand. thus, I see its better to use the regular asp:Table control to manually add the users. Plus, everything now is OK to me I just need a way to delete them.

Comment: you can webservice with the jquery to delete the data from table

Comment: can you please provide us with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

you should empty table and recreate the table and get username thorugh spliting imagebutton ID
by '_',So in loop when that username come you add continue statement.
some thing like that in Delete event :

```
string Username=((imagebutton)sender).ID.toString().tosplit('_')[0];
```